# Showing $\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt5+11}{2}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt5-11}{2}}=\sqrt{5} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

How do I prove the following equality?
$$\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt5+11}{2}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt5-11}{2}}=\sqrt{5} $$

My approach was to notice that the first term equals the golden ratio and the second term equals the reciprocal of the golden ratio, and adding them up would give $2$ times golden ratio $- 1$, which is $\sqrt5$, but how do I show that?

Comment: Hint: Expand $(\text{golden ratio})^5$.

Comment: Fifth roots are unique. If you can find a number whose fifth power is $(5\sqrt{5} + 11)/2$, then it is the only such number. I think what you've done is sufficient.

Comment: My favorite proof of what you already noticed is to use the Fibonacci numbers:$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^5=\varphi^5=F_5\varphi+F_4=5\varphi+3=\frac{5\sqrt5+11}2$$whence$$\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^5=\frac{5\sqrt5-11}2.$$Your result follows, as Theo Bendit confirmed.

Comment: "but how do I show that?" Show what exactly?  You show $\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt 5 + 11}2}=\phi = \frac {\sqrt 5 + 1}2$ by showing $(\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2)^5=\frac{5\sqrt 5+11}2$. You can use some cute golden ratio properties or you can just do it by brute force. You show $\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt 5-11}2}=\frac 1\phi$ by showing $\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt 5 + 11}2}\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt 5 - 11}2}=1$. You show $\phi + \frac 1\phi =2\phi -1$ by showing $\frac 2{\sqrt 5 +1}=\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}2$ and adding them.  And you show $2\phi-1=\sqrt 5$ by showing $(\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2-1)^2=5$.

Comment: @fleablood I wanted to show that the first term equals the golden ratio, so I thought of rationalizing the denominator like so : https://ibb.co/MVHKrs4 , but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Ah, well it'd be easier to prove $\phi^5 = \frac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}$ than to directly proving $(\frac {5\sqrt{5}+11}2)^{\frac 15} = \phi$.  A neat thing about $\phi$ is that as $\phi = \frac 1{\phi + 1}$ (by definition) $\phi^2+\phi =1$ and $\phi^2=1-\phi$.  So $\phi^5=\phi\phi^2\phi^2=\phi(1-\phi)(1-phi)=\phi(1-2\phi + \phi^2)=\phi(1-2\phi+1-\phi)=\phi(2-3\phi)=2\phi -3\phi^2=2\phi-3(1-\phi)=5\phi - 3=\frac {5(1+\sqrt 5)}2+3=\frac {5+5\sqrt 5}2 + \frac 62=\frac {5\sqrt{5} + 11}2$.

Answer (score 3):

You can raise both sides to the $5^{th}$ power and cancel out like terms of both sides until you see that both sides look the same. That's called brute force. We can save some times off by noting some relations between the terms of the sum on the left. Specifically, put $x = \sqrt[5]{\dfrac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}}\implies \dfrac{1}{x} = \sqrt[5]{\dfrac{5\sqrt{5}-11}{2}}$. So we show: $x+\dfrac{1}{x} = \sqrt{5}$. Let $a = x+\dfrac{1}{x}$, then we have: $a^5 = \left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^5= x^5+\dfrac{1}{x^5}+5\left(x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right)+10\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$. But $x^5+\dfrac{1}{x^5} = 5\sqrt{5}$, and $x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3} = \left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^3 - 3\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$. Substituting these identities into the equation above yields: $a^5 = 5\sqrt{5}+5(a^3-3a)+10a\implies a^5-5a^3+a-\sqrt{5} = 0$. Observe that the polynomial on the left hand side of this equation in $a$ has a factor $a - \sqrt{5}$ and it can be written as: $(a-\sqrt{5})\left(a^4 + \sqrt{5}a^3+1\right) = 0$. But $a > 0 \implies a^4+\sqrt{5}a^3 + 1  > 0$. Thus this equation implies: $a - \sqrt{5} = 0$ or $a = \sqrt{5}$. So $x+\dfrac{1}{x} = \sqrt{5}$. We're done !

Comment: +1, but this is much more complicated than what the OP already did.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but for the equation immediately before "Observe that the", instead of $a^5-5a^3+a-\sqrt{5} = 0$ I get $a^5 - 5a^3 + 5a - 5\sqrt 5 = 0.$ The left side is equal to $a^3(a + \sqrt 5)(a - \sqrt 5) + 5(a - \sqrt 5),$ which is $a - \sqrt 5$ times the positive (and thus not zero) quantity $a^3(a + \sqrt 5) + 5.$

Answer (score -1):

Hint : Use Binet's formula for $n=5,$ $ \displaystyle F_5 = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^5 - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^5\right) $.